# Does airflow have something like `yesterday_ds` / `tomorrow_ds` but for `@monthly` jobs?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a job that's using the `ds` variable to coordinate the amount of work that it processes, and it is scheduled to run daily with `@daily`.

```
select * from events
where date = '{{ ds }}';
```

However, I'd like to write a new version of it to be `@monthly`.  I don't have to change much, but I need access to the datestamp of the next run in order to cleanly port it over.

```
select * from events
where
date >= '{{ ds }}'
and
date < '{{ macros.ds_add(ds, 32) }}';
```

I can sort of get by through making a DAGrun's end-date be `{{ ds_add(ds, 32) }}` because my job is able to handle overlaps between runs, but I was hoping there was a way to have a datestamp that would be the first of the next month or the first of the previous month.

```
select * from events
where
date >= '{{ ds }}'
and
date < '{{ next_month }}';
```

How could I implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're running a recent version of Airflow and you set your schedule's interval to be @monthly then I think the `{{ data_interval_start }}` and `{{ data_interval_end }}` is what you're looking for. You can see all the macros [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html)

Comment: awesome! looks like it was added after 1.8.0 https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2033/commits/86505a45d714a08e4721b2d1df38c5983332d6bc

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{{ prev_execution_date }}` as well as `{{ next_execution_date }}` IF you are running an `@monthyl` schedule interval.

In the case that you are not doing so, you may want to develop a custom macro via the plugin system. These macros will enable you to develop a function to be passed into a template that meets your exact needs regardless of schedule_interval. You can use the existing [ds_add() and ds_format()](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/_modules/airflow/macros.html) macros as guidance.